# Register/Login Notworking android/PHP

Tags: php, android

Hi guys I set up a table on 000webhost.  I set it up with a column for id, name, username, age and password.  For some reason the username does not show up in the table when I run the code for the register and Im not sure what the error is.  Here is the code for Register.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("*****", "****", "*****", "****");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: `name, username` --- `siss` what doesn't match here. The order matters and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php would have told you about it.

Comment: Try to read the posted username, before the query runs.

Comment: @KoenHollander where do you see 5? edit: you deleted.

Comment: I set it up in the order shown in the PHP @Fred-ii-

Comment: Here `ssis` change it to that and magic might happen ;-) making sure the `age` column type is int. If not, use all `s` if it's a column type of string literals.

Comment: LOL, I new it there was someone who would have posted an answer just by seeing my comments. That is so rich.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Worked, thank you much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As I originally stated in comments:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442910/register-login-notworking-android-php/40442980#comment68132345_40442910)

You're trying to insert a string using the `i` parameter being an integer.

The order matters when binding.

You need to change your present parameters to `ssis` while making sure the age column is indeed an integer type.

Checking for errors on the query would have told you about it.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

I also hope you're not storing plain text passwords. Use `password_hash()` if you plan on going live with this.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but you will be hacked should this be the case.

Using a prepared statement without using a safe password hashing function won't guarantee your site from being compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Your bind statement has incorrect format specifiers.  Change this line

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
```

To

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $username, $age, $password);
```

Those specifiers need to match the column and variable type.  `S` for *string* and `i` for *Int*